# DirectX is missing

Tags: windows-7, directx

After installing a fresh copy of windows 7 I am not able to run a single game and I am having other problems related to DirectX - all dlls from System32 are missing and I do not know how to fix this. I reinstalled windows twice and upgraded once - nothing changed. The disk does not have the option to repair.

I have to mention that I have this OS as part of MS's student programs (Dream Spark, before that it was called MSDNAA). This is the second time I install Windows 7 from there, the first was very long time ago (on my laptop) and the OS is working perfectly until today (obviously it was a different distribution of windows 7).

So what might be the problem? My hardware (although my new PC has a very good one, the video is ATI 6850), the disk or the distribution?

UPDATE
I have all the latest updates, connection to internet; dxdiag is showing that the current version of DirectX is 11 and does not detect any problems. sfc /scannow did not detect any violations.

I am not able to install dxwebsetup (for DirectX 9.0c) because of the following error:

> Error creating process D:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP000.TMP\dxwsetup.exe. Reason: indows\system32\advpack.dll
>   (it really is indows, the W is missing).

When I go to the specified path I am able to find a dxwsetup.exe - when I run it it does not install anything and suggests to have a look at DXError and DirectX log files.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem although I am using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the latest drivers for the gfx card?
Also you could try to manually install the latest end-user version: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35

Comment: I bought my computer a week ago and installed every driver on the disk. dxwebsetup is the latest DirectX end-user version - check above for the error messages that I get when I try to install it.